# Manipulating a list with dynamically created controls

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say, I have a `List<Person> people`, where `Person` is a class containing three strings: a `Name`, `Surname` and `Age`. I also have six dynamically created `TextBox` controls, that are placed on a `Panel` control, and have a name assigned to them using a `for` loop. As well as, dynamically created `TextChanged` event for said `TextBox` controls. Currently the `List` consists of two entries `people.Add(new Person { Name = John, Surname = Johnson, Age = 25 });` and `people.Add(new Person { Name = Jack, Surname = Jackson, Age = 30 });`. I need the user to be able to change those `List<Person>` entries, by inputting text in the corresponding `Textbox`. So, the first `TextBox` changes the `people[0].Name`, second - `people[0].Surname`, third - `people[0].Age`, fourth - `people[1].Name`, and so on...

Comment: How about adding a few dynamically created line-breaks?? And throwing in a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at textbox tag property, it should help you here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx

You'd store the person object in the tag, and then when that textbox is updated, you can update the tag object which will in turn update the list for you. You'd need a way of telling what the textbox is (firstname, lastname age etc) which could be achieved by its name.

A better way of doing this though would be a custom control where all the textboxes are pre-build etc but sometimes I understand that on-the-fly building of the UI is needed.